# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=0$

Tags: limits

Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=0$. Can you give me a hint? Thanks to all.

Comment: Divide each part of the fraction by $n(n-1)$. BTW, what does "$x\to\infty$" mean here?

Comment: Are you sure that $n$ does not approach infinity, although the statement holds for $n \to 0$ as well...

Comment: Do you nean $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Really is $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=0$. I'm sorry.

Comment: "First one that shows it using Stirling's approximation loses"?

Comment: I really don't think you accepted the best answer. The answer given by Dr.MV is more elegant and was given before mine...

Comment: cf. previous comment of mine. I win! http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1814987/75808

Comment: Now, next step: "whoever proves it using the power series for $\exp$ wins"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

If$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log f(n)=-\infty$$
Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0$$

We can note that

$\log n!=\log 1+\log 2+\log 3+\cdots+\log n$

$\log n^2=2\log n$

Comment: This is just a hint btw

Comment: You may want to swap your "if" and your "then," or maybe phrase it as an equivalence instead of an implication.

Comment: @ClementC. I see your point, will edit

Comment: Why was it downvoted? Admittedly, it is a much more complicated solution that the other ones, but it is a valid and correct one.

Answer (score 1):

This is another, rather sneaky way of doing it. 
$ Theorem :$ For $L$ belongs to set $R$ If $lim |(x_{n+1}/x_{n})| = L$ then sequence,

$x_n$ is convergent if $L<1$, and

$x_n$ is divergent if $L>1$

However it must be noted that if $L=1$, then we don't have any information about its convergence

Comment: And if it series does converge then sequence must tend to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You already got one hint, with exact equalities, here's one with inequalities:

You can safely assume that $n>4$, in which case

$$n!=n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-3)!$$

and for $n>4$, you have that $n-3>1$, so $$n!\geq n(n-1)(n-2)$$

meaning that $$\frac{n^2}{n!} < \frac{n^2}{n(n-1)(n-2)}=\frac{n^2}{n^3-3n^2+2n}=\frac{1}{n-3+\frac{2}{n}}.$$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

For $n>2$,
$$
\frac{n^2}{n!}=
\frac{n}{n}\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2}\frac{1}{(n-3)!}<
2\frac{1}{n-2}
$$
because $\dfrac{n}{n-1}<2$ and $\dfrac{1}{(n-3)!}\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}{n^{2} \over n!}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{n \over \pars{n - 1}!} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\pars{n + 1} - n \over \bracks{\pars{n + 1} - 1}! - \pars{n - 1}!} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over \pars{n - 1}\pars{n - 1}!} = \color{#f00}{0}
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Not the most elegant but...

Hint: Use [**Stirling's Approxmation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$\lim \frac{n^2}{n!}$$

$$ = \lim \frac{n^2}{n!} \frac{n!}{\sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n}$$

$$ = \lim \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n}$$

Now compute:

$$\lim \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n} (\frac{n}{e})^n}$$

$$ = \lim \frac{n^{3/2}}{(\frac{n}{e})^n}$$

Use LHR somewhere